# Prevent memory leak in long polling ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello to everyone I trying to call to my api each 1s but the problem is My browser stop working well because the memory issue,  I have some like this

```
  function getContact() {

        $.getJSON(setUrl(pagination, page), function (response) {


                contactList = response.DATA;

                if (refresh) {

                   console.log('refreshing the view')
                    contactList = handleListContact(contactList);
                    contactView(contactList);
                    refresh = false;
                }


            setTimeout(getContact, 1000);
        });

    }
```

I do this because I want to know if something is change in the databases I can refresh my view with the new data, but after a while my browser memory become to high, is a better way for get done this I can't use any framework or socket this is my only way

Comment: I'm guessing it's a recursion issue, `getContact()` is calling itself, infinitely.

Comment: What is the value of `refresh`?

Comment: the value is false by default is become true if i need refresh the view

Comment: You are continually calling the `getContact()` function, recursively. Every time you process a response you call `getContact()` one second later and there's no return.

Comment: Nunchy is right about the recursion. Quick fix is to remove `setTimeout(getContact, 1000);` and start the polling process by `setInterval(getContact, 1000);` outside of getContact function. However this is still not the ideal solution.